# How to find views inside custom gridView to change them

Tags: android, gridview

Can you help me to find `TextView` at the `onClick` location so that I can do stuffs like `setText` , apply animation, change background, etc.

my gridView in MainActivity

```
    final GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gv.setAdapter(g);
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //TODO: IN HERE I WANT TO CHANGE TEXT, APPLY ANIMATION,AND CHANGE COLOR OF TEXTVIEW PRESENT IN CUSTOM LAYOUT 
            // SO I WANT TO FIND THE TEXTVIEW AS WE NORMALLY DO WITH findViewById();
        }
    });
```

my custom layout I what to find `TextView` atomicNumber so that in can apply change text and do other stuffs.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="50dip"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:id="@+id/atomicNumber"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="H"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:id="@+id/elementSymbol"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to find the solution but could not find one

Comment: What do you want to find from the custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it inside your onItemClickListener. Here you go :

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //TODO: IN HERE I WANT TO CHANGE TEXT, APPLY ANIMATION,AND CHANGE COLOR OF TEXTVIEW PRESENT IN CUSTOM LAYOUT 
            // SO I WANT TO FIND THE TEXTVIEW AS WE NORMALLY DO WITH findViewById();

       // You can use view object to apply findviewbyId method             
       TextView myTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextview);

        }
    });
```

Comment: brother can you add even how to find the view outside the onItemClick method. To address View in other methods in main activity